# Is paver sand too wet to use?

Tags: patio

I had to dig up part of my patio to move electrical conduit. So I removed it all and re-compacted the stone - amazingly it is not as 'level' as it was before I started... Only dug up about 20 sq ft of stone. Any way, waiting for more than a day without rain or cold. I have 130 square feet. Picked up 21 bags of sand - turns out to be half of what I need as the undulations etc. in the stone surface seems to be a bit off. It poured yesterday and even though they were in plastic, the sand is like mud. So I just spread some out to dry. I'm worried that if I start with mud-sand, by the time I get around to finishing, I will have dry sand for the next half. Will it matter if I start putting down the square cement 2" blocks on very wet sand and then later using dry sand? A hot tub is going over a section of this.If not for all the snow in March I wouldn't be asking this now... I'm using that bagged stuff from blue store in the purple bags.

Comment: You dug it up to remove it?  Don’t do that in the future,  Abandon it. It’s best not to disturb pavers on a sand bed, it’s hard to put back, especially with undisturbed areas that must be matched.  Are you planning to hand tamp or get a mechanical compactor?

Comment: Did you tamp the sand level with the existing prior to laying the brick? The old sand has settled and already compacted from years of being walked on.

Comment: had to dig out conduit. When I put stone back I hand tamped it as I filled. I removed ALL of the old pavers 12" sq. And removed most of the old sand. Where the old tub was there was no 'sand'. An ez pad was there. So what sand  I could not remove without disturbing the base too much I scrathced up and broom it all over the surface. The I did the entire area with a plate vibrator/compactor. When I went to screed the new sand it was like mud. So I waited for a couple sunny days to try again - today.

Comment: Tyson - I did abandon it in place. But I still had to dig up for the NEW conduit.Would rather do the extra work than having electrical conduit above patio running to hot tub.

Comment: new question: All tell me to compact the pavers after I lay them. I think it a waste of energy. These are going to be 16" sq laid edge to edge. I will firm them with a mallet as I go. There will be 'zero' clearance between them. I think this is what I did when I first installed it almost 18 years ago and it has been solid since. I'm gonna make a tight fit all around the edges - timber. I have a drain trough cut at low corner for rain to run off.